# Thinkpad dock: External monitors not recognized after 15.04 upgrade

Tags: 15.04, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

On Thinkpad L540 with intel graphics:

External monitors are not recognized in display settings when plugged in (into any port including VGA).

They *are* recognized after a reboot (not after logout).
After plugging out and the in again they are not recognized.

A monitor plugged into the internal VGA is recognized instantly.

Everything used to work with 14.10, but stopped with 15.04.

Comment: Crosslinking bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1530171